# DLL problem (COM)

Tags: asp.net

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {B4E1B2EC-151B-11D2-926A-006008123235} failed due to the following error: 80040154. in my application i use third party tool (aspjpeg) for reseizing the image. when i run this application i get this error please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably dealing with a Class Not Registered error, as described at http://support.software602.com/kb/view.aspx?articleID=987.  Is there an installation program for this third-party tool.  There may be missing registry entries describing this COM component.

**A bit more description:**

The DLL you're adding may have dependencies on other COM objects in other DLLs.  Let's say that COM Component A has a dependency on COM Component B.  This dependency is not from one file to another, but from one file to a what's called a class id (also referred to as CLSID).

In this case, say that COM Component A refers to CLSID "1234."  A registry check is made under the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID folder for a folder with a matching CLSID.  Once found, that folder's InprocServer32 folder is read and the exact path to the DLL housing COM Component B is determined, and then loaded.

In short, you're getting error messages because one or more of the registry entries mentioned above are missing.

**EDIT**: Added details about how COM components are referenced and loaded by the COM runtime.

Comment: i don't about that i add reference like i add dll of the tool into my application.when i run i get this error